# Issue with resolving the file url in windows 8 using Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a windows 8 app. I am using cordova plugins to capture image and upload to server. But when I am resolving the file url  using

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, onResolveSuccess,onResolveFail);

It gets fail with error code - 5.

file URI is like-

ms-appdata:///local/picture001.jpg  - when captured image

blob:1439104B-EB70-4731-8039-9493259BCC4B - when select from existing images

what path should be there and how it will come.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a url like this to cordova on Windows.

```
fileURI = fileURI.replace("ms-appdata:///local/", Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + "\\");
```

Comment: How would you parse the URL when the image you want to display (via plugin) is in the Cordova www folder? The one with index.html and other stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have solved this, but my solution is that I don't get that blob and I don't use that resolveLocalFileSystemURL. I just change option destinationType value in navigator.camera.getPicture when selecting existing file on windows phone to NATIVE_URI, so it becomes:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { 
  quality: 50, 
  destinationType: destinationType.NATIVE_URI,
  sourceType: source 
});
```

So instead of blob, I got good image with URL.